# how to convert the decompiled code to the correct source code?

Tags: asp.net, dotpeek

I have one online published project but i don't have it's original source code so i used dotpeek decompiler to get source code but i didn't get right source code from that.Source code having some errors so how can i convert that decompiled source code to correct source code.i have one example of it which shows some errors.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage IndexAction()
    {
      try
      {
        return this.Request.CreateResponse<IQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType17<ICollection<ContactPersonMaster>, long, string, string, BranchMaster, CompanyMaster, ClientMaster, DateTime?, DateTime?, long, long?, string, string, long, string, string, string, string, string>>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.db.ProjectMasters.Select(s => new
        {
          ContactPersonMasters = s.ContactPersonMasters,
          ProjectId = s.ProjectId,
          ProjectName = s.ProjectName,
          Description = s.Description,
          BranchMaster = s.BranchMaster,
          CompanyMaster = s.CompanyMaster,
          ClientMaster = s.ClientMaster,
          StartDate = s.StartDate,
          EndDate = s.EndDate,
          Cost = s.Cost,
          tonnage = s.tonnage,
          FileNo = s.FileNo,
          FileName = s.FileName,
          TotalHours = s.TotalHours,
          ShelfDetail = s.ShelfDetail,
          RoomNo = s.RoomNo,
          WardRobe = s.WardRobe,
          DrawerNo = s.DrawerNo,
          Status = s.Status
        }));
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        this.logger.Error((object) "An error happened on Project master API index!", ex);
        if (WebApiApplication.IsShowError)
          return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "");
      }
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: use justdecompile product of telerick. There is option to conver whole things to project. Try it.

Comment: Unethical much?